# How To Fetch Data from child table using JPA Query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I have used @JoinTable in model and created Table and i have saved Data.

Now i want to fetch Data from that child table..How can i get it through JPA Query..

My Code is,

```
@Entity

public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private User user;

@Column
private Integer handicap;

@OneToOne(targetEntity=StudentPro.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
mappedBy="student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private StudentPro studentPro;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "student_favourite_pro",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pro_id")}
)
private List<Pro> favouritePros = new ArrayList<Pro>();
```

.

```
public StudentPro getStudentPro() {
    return this.studentPro;}

public void setStudentPro(StudentPro studentPro) {
    this.studentPro = studentPro;}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;}

public User getUser() {
    return user;}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;}

public Integer getHandicap() {
    return handicap;}

public void setHandicap(Integer handicap) {
    this.handicap = handicap;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);}

public void addFavouritePro(Pro pro) {
    favouritePros.add(pro);}

public List<Pro> getFavouritePros() {
    return favouritePros;}}
```

I want to fetch data from student_favourite_pro table.How can i do that?

Thanks In Advance

Lakshmi Priya.K

Comment: To what purpose do you want data from student_favourite_pro?  As it is just a relation table, having a bunch of student and pro ids isn't going to mean much to your application, will it?  JPA deals with the Student and Pro entities, so queries will be based on them as well, and presumably they contain the information your app will want to deal with, while student_favourite_pro just helps define the relationship.  For example JPQL "select p from Student s join s.favouritePros p where ..." allows you to use the relationship to get what your app might really want.